# Cut a bagel into interlocking rings

Tags: geometry

Let's say you have a standard bagel (one that is NOT pre-sliced).  How can you cut this bagel into two interlocking rings?  The rings must never be broken.

Comment: http://www.georgehart.com/bagel/bagel.html

Comment: @skv That's an answer ;-)

Comment: :) Yes, I just did not feel good about writing that out as an answer because it was not nearly mine, also I could not modify anything there to make it sound like I have added value, so just left it there

Comment: The answer @skv posted is the only one that can fulfill the requirements, I think..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok Just to ensure that this question gets an answer I am posting this, and attributing it to community.

Credits to http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2232924/How-make-Mobius-bagel-Sliced-just-right-breakfast-snack-makes-linked-halves-curious-mathematical-properties.html

The basic concept is to consider the third dimension and visualize four key points.  Center the bagel at the origin, circling the Z axis.

A is the highest point above the +X axis.  B is where the +Y axis enters the bagel.
C is the lowest point below the -X axis.  D is where the -Y axis exits the bagel.

Cut through the line ABCDA.  Then turn the bagel over and make the same cut again.  Here is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dN8AwGUaqDA) showing how to cut the bagel.

[image]

Comment: I changed the image because I think it would be useful to show the line you need to cut through, as well as the final result.

Comment: Is the red line just the other end of  the same cut? That is, 180 degrees opposite the black line?

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop You have to turn the bagel over and make the same cut again - I edited the answer to reflect that and included a link to a video.

Comment: Why\how is there 'slightly more surface area'?